# Is it physically possible to play these notes together?

Tags: piano

[image: Stack of notes]

This is from Chopin's Op. 48 Nr 1

How do I play these for notes with ny left hand? Seems impossible.

Comment: It's possible that you just had smaller hands than Chopin.  Is this just a problem you have with your left hand?  Can you span a major tenth with your right hand?

Comment: Related:  [How to alter piano music with left-hand octaves to require a smaller span](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/73809/);  [Difficulty playing piano due to my small hands and short fingers](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12523/);  [Do the hands' sizes affect piano learning/performance?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8013/)

Comment: This reminds me of transcribed sheet music of Tom Brier's works, which consistently have tenths in the left hand precisely because Brier plays them in the original audio (and video).

Comment: Also, this chord looks achievable if your right hand plays the top note and your left hand plays the others.

Comment: I can do it, but if you have smaller hands this is of course harder. But what if you simply take the Ab (or even the D) into the right hand?